# Can we produce energy from pure substance having considerable mass?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, mass-energy

According to Einstein's formula, $E=mc^2$. Any substance which has mass can be converted into energy or energy is also existing in the form of mass. So I am very much interested to build a machine which can convert the oil (sesame) into usable energy. If anyone interested in the following topic can approach me.

Comment: Burning the oil accomplishes your goal. And it is easy to do.

Comment: > So I am very much interested to build a machine which can convert the oil(sesame) into usable energy. If anyone interested in the following topic can approach me.


Not only you my friend, the whole world is interested in the topic. You can do this most efficiently by building a machine which can manufacture antimatter for your matter and then annihilating them.

Comment: Sesame oil is relatively difficult to produce. Why not choose the cheapest possible substance to convert into energy, such as trash, or sand?

Comment: Are you asking a question about physics, or are you trying to find partners for research and development - or a business venture?

Answer (score 1):

Einstein's equation does not indicate how mass can be converted into energy.  It only says that mass and energy are equivalent.

Nobody has as yet found a way to convert mass directly and completely into energy.  The best that can be done at present is nuclear fission or fusion reactions.  Fission is already well established in the nuclear energy industry.   Fusion has not yet resulted in an economical source of energy but is still being developed.  In both cases only a small percentage of the mass has been converted into energy.  Nuclear reactions merely re-arrange the constituents of atomic nuclei : no sub-atomic particles are annihilated and converted completely to energy.

The only way that sesame oil can be converted into energy is by burning it. Per kg of fuel, this releases only about a millionth of the energy available in nuclear reactions.

Comment: One can argue that a black hole is a lot more efficient, they are just hard to come by. :-)